# Magento 2 | Join table catalog_product_entity_tier_price to collection

Tags: magento2, collection, filter, catalogsearch, tierprice

I'm trying to filter my product collection by tier price.

I currently have this code but it doesn't work and it returns error:

```
protected $_productCollectionFactory;
        
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

public function getProductCollectionTot()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        
        
        $collection->getSelect()->join('catalog_product_entity_tier_price as tier', 'price_index.entity_id = tier.entity_id');

        $collection->addFinalPrice()
              ->addMinimalPrice()
              ->getSelect()
              ->where('tier.all_groups = 0')
              ->where('price_index.Tier_price < price_index.price');
              
        return $collection;
    }
```

How can I filter my collection by tier price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed joining product collection with `catalog_product_index_price` table. Please make changes in your query as follows:

```
    public function getProductCollectionTot() {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        $collection->getSelect()->join('catalog_product_index_price as price_index', 'e.entity_id = price_index.entity_id');    // Add this join statement
        $collection->getSelect()->join('catalog_product_entity_tier_price as tier', 'price_index.entity_id = tier.entity_id');

        $collection->addFinalPrice()
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->getSelect()
            ->where('tier.all_groups = 0')
            ->where('price_index.Tier_price < price_index.price');

        return $collection;
    }
```

Hope this may help you. Please let me know if it worked for you or not. Happy to Help :)

Comment: Man, now works!! The issue was in last "->where". I fixed from ->where('price_index.Tier_price < price_index.price'); to ->where('tier.value < price_index.price'); Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: Only problem: When I try to create foreach it goes into error and tells me: "Item (Magento \ Catalog \ Model \ Product \ Interceptor) with the same ID" 42 "already exists". How can i do for fix this issue? This happen when join the two tables...